# Dijkstra-like routing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, scala, graph

I've got the following code to find the shortest path between two nodes using almost-Dijkstra's-algorithm which was written for an exercise, and I'm looking for things to improve my general Scala style. What I currently have:

```
  object Graphs {
    case class Node[T](value : T)
    case class Edge[T](from : Node[T], to : Node[T], dist : Int)

    def shortest[T](edges : Set[Edge[T]], start : T, end : T) : Option[List[Edge[T]]] = {

      val tentative = edges.flatMap(e => Set(e.from, e.to)).map(n => (n, if (n.value == start)  Some(List.empty[Edge[T]]) else None )).toMap

      def rec(tentative : Map[Node[T], Option[List[Edge[T]]]]) : Option[List[Edge[T]]] = {
        val current = tentative.collect{ case (node, Some(route)) => (node, route)}.toList.sortBy(_._2.length).headOption

        current match {
          case None => None
          case Some((node, route)) => {
            if (node.value == end) Some(route)
            else {
              val fromHere = edges.filter(e => e.from == node)
              val tentupdates = for(edge <- fromHere if tentative.contains(edge.to)) yield {
                tentative.get(edge.to) match {
                  case None => throw new Error("broken algorithm")
                  case Some(Some(knownroute)) if (knownroute.map(_.dist).sum < route.map(_.dist).sum + edge.dist) => (edge.to, Some(knownroute))
                  case _ =>(edge.to, Some(edge :: route))
                }
              }

              val newtentative = (tentative ++ tentupdates) - node
              rec(newtentative)
            }
          }
        }
      }
      rec(tentative)
    }
  }
```

First of, getting some feedback on the correctness would be nice.

For the algorithm itself, I already know it could be refined by keeping track of the unevaluated edges, and for a more general solution keeping a second accumulator with the solved set wouldn't cost me much more, but I get the general idea of how to implement that.

I'm thinking of replacing Node with Scalaz TypeTags, and would like some feedback on whether that's a good idea.

Other than that, I'd like some feedback on general style, and how to improve readability - I have quite long lines now for example. Also, types like `Map[Node[T], Option[List[Edge[T]]]]` sort of hurt my eyes, I'd love to know how I could improve that.

Lastly, I really don't like my

```
case Some(Some(knownroute)) if (knownroute.map(_.dist).sum < route.map(_.dist).sum + edge.dist) => (edge.to, Some(knownroute))
case _ => (edge.to, Some(edge :: route))
```

the first case is only used as a filter, I'm actually looking for something like

```
case None || Some(Some(knownroute)) if (knownroute.map(_.dist).sum > route.map(_.dist).sum + edge.dist) => (edge.to, Some(edge :: route))
```

but I don't know how to express that.

Comment: Nice problem! Your search algorithm is quite custom. Is it okay if we change the implementation a bit? If not then could you please add comments of what you're doing to make it easier for us? Usually Dijkstra uses distances to keep track of its progress.

Comment: This keeps track of distances as well, but the distance is evaluated on the fly as `route.map(_.distance).sum`. I know this is inefficient if the routes are quite large. I considered keeping a `Tuple2[List[Edge[T], Int]` rather than just a `List[Edge[T]`, but I figured that was trivial anyway, and would clutter the clarity of the implementation (a production version would have it, but this is basically a toy). If you would like to propose changes to the algorithm, by all means do!

Comment: If that's the case then `.sortBy(_._2.length)` is not optimal. It should be adding the weights together and choosing the next candidate based on the shortest weighted path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things how this could be improved.

First, a few minor quibbles about syntax:

- When using a type annotation, do not put a space before the `:` – `name: Type`, please. ([source](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#annotations))
- In a chain of higher-order methods, do not use the `.` to invoke the method. For example this

  ```scala
  val tentative = edges.flatMap(e => Set(e.from, e.to)).map(n => (n, if (n.value == start)  Some(List.empty[Edge[T]]) else None )).toMap
  ```

  should be

  ```scala
  val tentative = edges flatMap (e => Set(e.from, e.to)) map (n => (n, if (n.value == start) Some(List.empty[Edge[T]]) else None)).toMap
  ```

  ([source](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#higherorder_functions))
- When a chain of transformations is very long, splitting inside the lambdas can be an acceptable solution:

  ```scala
  val tentative = edges flatMap (
      e => Set(e.from, e.to)
    ) map (n =>
      (n, if (n.value == start) Some(List.empty[Edge[T]]) else None)
    ).toMap
  ```
- `yield { block }` is “evil” and should be avoided. `for`-comprehensions can be rewritten less clearly with `flatMap` and `filter`, but this may actually be preferable when the transformations are deeply nested.

Now let's look at this piece of your code:

```scala
for(edge <- fromHere if tentative.contains(edge.to)) yield {
  tentative.get(edge.to) match {
    case None => throw new Error("broken algorithm")
    case Some(Some(knownroute)) if (knownroute.map(_.dist).sum < route.map(_.dist).sum + edge.dist) => (edge.to, Some(knownroute))
    case _ =>(edge.to, Some(edge :: route))
  }
}
```

As I said, this could be rewritten to avoid the comprehension.

```scala
fromHere filter (edge => tentative.contains(edge.to)) flatMap { edge =>
  tentative.get(edge.to) match {
    case None => throw new Error("broken algorithm")
    case Some(Some(knownroute)) if (knownroute.map(_.dist).sum < route.map(_.dist).sum + edge.dist) => (edge.to, Some(knownroute))
    case _ => (edge.to, Some(edge :: route))
  }
}
```

The `tentative.get(…)` returns an `Option`, which will be `None` if no element for that key was found. But that means we can get rid of the `filter`! Instead, we `map` over the result of the `get`, which removes one level of `Option`s:

```scala
fromHere flatMap { edge =>
  tentative.get(edge.to) map {
    case Some(knownroute) if (knownroute.map(_.dist).sum < route.map(_.dist).sum + edge.dist) => (edge.to, Some(knownroute))
    case _ => (edge.to, Some(edge :: route))
  }
}
```

Destructuring the `Option` with Pattern matching is a bit tedious. Actually, we want to do one thing, `orElse` some default case.

```scala
fromHere flatMap { edge =>
  tentative.get(edge.to) map { maybeRoute =>
    maybeRoute filter (knownroute =>
      knownroute.map(_.dist).sum < route.map(_.dist).sum + edge.dist
    ) map (knownroute =>
      Pair(edge.to, Some(knownroute)
    ) getOrElse (Pair(edge.to, Some(edge :: route)))
  }
}
```

But this is an unreadable mess! Yes, it somehow is. We can improve this by adding a `Route` class, e.g:

```scala
case class Route[T](route: List[Edge[T]], dist: Int) {
  val length = route.length

  def this(route: List[Edge[T]]) = this(route, route map (_.dist) sum)

  def this() = this(List.empty[Edge[T]], 0)

  def ::(edge: Edge[T]) = Route(edge :: route, dist + edge.dist)
}

val tentative: Map[Node[T], Option[Route[T]] = ...
```

The main advantage is that this keeps track of a route's distance, which means the above code becomes the slightly more accessible

```scala
fromHere flatMap { edge =>
  tentative.get(edge.to) map { maybeRoute =>
    val maybeBetterRoute =
      maybeRoute filter (knownRoute => knownRoute.dist < route.dist + edge.dist)
    maybeBetterRoute map (knownRoute =>
      Pair(edge.to, Some(knownroute)
    ) getOrElse (
      Pair(edge.to, Some(edge :: route))
    )
  }
}
```

You calculate the `fromHere` each time, which is an *O(n)* calculation, I think:

```scala
val fromHere = edges.filter(e => e.from == node)
```

It may be better to build a `Map[Node[T], List[Edge[T]]]` before the recursion, which is also a fairly cheap operation:

```scala
val edgesBySource = edges groupBy (_.from)
```

then: `val fromHere = edgesBySource.get(node).flatten`. I assume this would pay off soon for non-tiny graphs.

Comment: great stuff! I'll get cracking on it!